# question about structural casual model

Tags: data-analysis

So I am struggling with understading Structural Causal Modelling. I have the following model

$$z=Nz$$
$$y=-z+Ny$$
$$x=2*y+3*z+Nx$$

I have the following variable values

$$Ny=0; Nz=0; Nx=0; z=5  $$

If i intervene the variable $y=7$ what is the result then?

From my own calculations i have come to the conclusion 20, but I am really not sure. Can anyone help me?